# Drag to archive in Trello?

Tags: trello

I have the Trello Android app installed and it has a really nice function. When you want to archive an item, you can simply drag it to an area on the screen which will archive the item. There doesn't seem to be an equivalent in the Trello web application.

Is there a way that I can enable drag to archive in the main desktop Trello web application?

Answer (score 4):

I am not aware of any drag-and-drop approach to archiving cards. A quick read of the manpages also indicates this to be the case.

An alternative way of quickly archiving cards is to hover over the card in question, then press the 'c' key on your keyboard.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware of that. Since they already incorporate dragging actions to move between lists, there should really be an archive option IMO.

Comment: True. The team at Trello are very friendly, it might be worth sending an email to them at feature-ideas@trello.com with you suggestion.